# Property 'form' does not exist on type 'LoginComponent'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

im having trouble to add a form to my website on angular, in the title its shows what its the error that VScode shows me.

Here is the LoginComponent.html
On line 1 under the word "form" its where vscode indicate my error, also on the words "form" on the bottom of the code.

```
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email: </label>                          
        <input type="email" formControlName="email">
    </div>
   
    <div *ngIf="Mail?.errors  && Mail?.touched">    
        <p *ngIf="Mail?.hasError('required')" class="error">
            El email es requerido.
        </p>
        <p *ngIf="Mail?.hasError('email')" class="error">
            El formato del email debe ser válido.
          </p>
    </div>

    <br/>
    <div>
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password: </label>
        <input type="password" formControlName="password" [class.border-danger]="MailValid">
    </div>
    
    <div *ngIf="Password?.errors  && Password?.touched">
    <p *ngIf="Password?.hasError('required')" class="error">
      El password es requerido.
    </p>
    <p *ngIf="Password?.errors?.minlength
" class="error">
      El password debe ser de 8 o más caracteres.
    </p>
  </div>
    <br/>
    <div>
        <button   type="submit">Iniciar Sesión</button>
    </div>
</form>

<div>
 <p>Un debuger para mostrar que es posible hacer un biding directo al formulario <strong>{{form.value.email}} </strong><strong>{{form.value.password}} </strong><p> <--here also shows me the error.
<br> 

</div>
```

---

And here is my LoginComponent.ts code, also shows me the error message "Property 'form' does not exist on type 'LoginComponent'" in every form word appareance.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  // Inyectar en el constructor el formBuilder
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){ 
    ///Creamos el grupo de controles para el formulario de login
    this.form= this.formBuilder.group({
      password:['',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
      email:['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
   })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  get Password(){
    return this.form.get("password");
  }
 
  get Mail(){
   return this.form.get("email");
  }

  get PasswordValid(){
    return this.Password?.touched && !this.Password?.valid;
  }

  get MailValid() {
    return false
  }
 

  onEnviar(event: Event){
    // Detenemos la propagación o ejecución del compotamiento submit de un form
    event.preventDefault; 
 
    if (this.form.valid){
      // Llamamos a nuestro servicio para enviar los datos al servidor
      // También podríamos ejecutar alguna lógica extra
      alert("Todo salio bien ¡Enviar formuario!")
    }else{
      // Corremos todas las validaciones para que se ejecuten los mensajes de error en el template     
      this.form.markAllAsTouched(); 
    }
 
  }

}
```

Comment: Please update all relevant portions of your code only in the question section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume one of the following is missing.

1. You haven't referenced the form in the HTML like `<form [formGroup]="form">`
2. You're missing the `ReactiveFormsModule` in your `app.module.ts`

But based on your code, I'm wondering... where did you even declare `form`? Don't you have any linter installed? No surprise that the template cannot find the form.

Comment: Hi, tk for the answer. It was the first problem of the two you wrote. Really a simple mistake but im new to Angular and wasnt havingit. Thanks again for taking the time :)